# Partial View of search module gives " insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely"

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been stuck in this problem for a while now, and tried solutions suggested by other questions asked on Stackoverflow.

So, basically I have created a search module for my website, which works fine when called by its Url and returns a result.  However, when I use it throught its partial view on the main layout page, it gives this error:

> "Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'"

and later on converted into:

> "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can
>   happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on
>   the stack using too much stack space."

Here is the code of Controller

```
public ActionResult SearchResult()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResult(String h)
{
    string s = Request.Form["name"];
    var dataContext = new AutonomousEntities();
    var saleRepository = new Repository<Sale>(dataContext);
    var brandrepository = new Repository<Brand>(dataContext);
    string result="";
    List<Sale> sd = new List<Sale>();
    IEnumerable<Sale> SaleList = saleRepository.GetAll();
    IEnumerable<Brand> BrandList = brandrepository.GetAll();


    List<Sale> sales = SaleList.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i <SaleList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Sale t = sales.ElementAt(i);

        string name=t.Promotion.Promotion_Name;

        if (name.Contains(s))
        {
            sd.Add(t);
        }
    }

    return View("GetAllSale",sd);
}
```

This is my View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult","Search",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input  name="name" style="margin-top:20px;" type="text" /> 
    <input type="submit" style="color:#1FABBC;" value="Search" />
}
```

And this is the layout page's line on which error is coming:

```
 <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  @Html.Action("SearchResult", "Search")</span>
```

I have already tried removing `[HttpGet]` and `layout=null`

Comment: `@Html.Action()` calls you server method which returns the partial view which then calls `@Html.Action()` which calls you server method which returns the partial view which then calls `@Html.Action()` which calls .... and so on and so on (an infinite loop)

Comment: and how to stop it from calling itself again and again ?

Comment: Two thing; I think the part that is missing is that you have two calls, but your `Action()` call does not specify an `h` parameter so the first `SearchResult()` method is called (recursively) and I would highly recommend `return PartialView()` so the html won't include the layout (even though you've specified it in the view, a simple mistake can be costly).